Error "Composer could not detect the root package (laravel/laravel) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See https://getcomposer.org/root-version" Laravel
Error "Composer could not detect the root package (laravel/laravel) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See https://getcomposer.org/root-version"
I'm using Laravel 10, PHP 8.2.9 and the latest version of Composer, this warning appears when I try to install AdminLTE and coincidentally, when I open AdminLTE's Register or Login, its CSS is not applied (Not even in your dashboard )
I haven't tried to do anything yet for fear of messing up.

Are you facing any real issue? "Its CSS is not applied" is not a problem related to Composer

I was having the same issue.
In the new version of Composer, after version 2.7.0, there must be a "version" property at the beginning of the file composer.json, below the "name", like this:
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "version": "11",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",

Just add this property and the message will disappear.
Source
